# Git push error "fatal: repository not found" after changing repository hosting

Tags: git

I have transferred my repository, I am still allowed to push, how I'm getting the following error when I do:

> fatal: repository 'https://me@bitbucket.org/me/optinisations.git/' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the old origin first:

```
git remote remove origin
```

Then add the new origin:

```
git remote add origin https://new_server.com/path/to/repo.git
```

Now you should be able to push again.

Comment: If I do `git remote -d origin` it will not clear my commits, no?

Comment: No, it will not harm you. However, you should make a copy of your clone anytime you are unsure with git.

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon It should be: `remove`, not `-d`. I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]

git remote set-url origin <yournewurl>
```

Comment: I get `There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details git pull <remote> <branch> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with: git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> myBr`

Comment: I did it, but it still tells me that, I thing it is because I have more branches